# How to draw a graph with NetworkX based on adjacency of nodes

Tags: python, graph, networkx, graph-theory

I'm seeing in many research papers graphical representations of directed graphs where nodes seem to be placed depending on their adjacency rather than on features for the x and y axis. An example of it, from `Conover, Michael D., et al. "Political polarization on twitter." Fifth international AAAI conference on weblogs and social media. 2011.`

[image]

How can I obtain such a representation from a pre constructed NetworkX [DiGraph](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/digraph.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetworkX has built in functions to draw graphs (see [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/drawing.html)). You can basically call them and pass the DiGraph you constructed. Copying from one of their own examples:

```
G = nx.dodecahedral_graph()
nx.draw(G)
nx.draw(G, pos=nx.spring_layout(G))
```